# Please aid me on this simple SQL Question. Cannot figure it out

Tags: sql, syntax, analysis

How would you update the query to only include the user's name if the user was created after the visit? The user table includes a field created_on that indicates when the user record was created.

```
SELECT v.visit_id, v.visit_datetime, v.page_url, v.user_id, u.name 
FROM web_visits AS v LEFT JOIN user AS u ON v.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: `include the user's name`: does this mean include/exclude the entire row from the results, or just suppress (show blank) for the user's name if created before the visit?

Comment: So I believe the end result should only be results from u.name if the created_on column from the user table is after v.visit_datetime. Please let me know if that didnt answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the ON condition if you still want to see the visits, but not the users (if created afterwards)

```
SELECT v.visit_id, v.visit_datetime, v.page_url, v.user_id, u.name 
FROM web_visits AS v 
     
     LEFT JOIN user AS u 
     ON v.user_id = u.id
     and u.created_on<=v.visit_datetime
```